# Automatically insert null safety operator when typing property name

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to configure Android Studio, to insert '?' automatically when typing nullable property (like Xcode does in Swift)?

Example class:

```
data class Test(
    val testVal: Boolean?,
    val childTest: Test?
)
```

I would like to achieve that when I type:

```
test.childTest.testVal
```

The editor would automatically add '?' before the  `.testVal` and other optionals in the path.

Comment: This has to be one of those things that's so simple, it's not even an issue. Or Android devs don't know how bad we have it compared to Xcode's auto nil safety feature.